# Remove characters from a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, replace, char

I only have access to 'C' and need to replace characters within a character array.  I have not come up with any clean solutions for this relatively simple procedure.

I am passed a character array, for example:

```
char strBuffer[] = "/html/scorm12/course/course_index.jsp?user_id=100000232&amp;course_id=100000879&amp;course_prefix=ACQ&amp;version=2&amp;scorm_version=3&amp;roster_id=100011365&amp;course_name=Test%20Course%201.2&amp;mode=browse&amp;course_number=0000&amp;mode_id=1";
```

I need to modify this buffer to replace all the `&amp;` with `&`.  The resulting buffer does not have to overwrite strBuffer (a new buffer can be created).

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

In the past I have done the strstr function in a loop, but was looking for a simpler solution, perhaps the C equivalent to the String.Replace method.

**Edit:**

For my immediate needs, the following is all that I need.

```
char strBuffer[] = "/html/scorm12/course/course_index.jsp?user_id=100000232&amp;course_id=100000879&amp;course_prefix=ACQ&amp;version=2&amp;scorm_version=3&amp;roster_id=100011365&amp;course_name=Test%20Course%201.2&amp;mode=browse&amp;course_number=0000&amp;mode_id=1";
char strTemp[1024];
char *s = (char*)strBuffer;
int i=0;

while (*s)
{
    strTemp[i++] = *s;
    if (strncmp(s,"&amp;",5) == 0)
    {
        s += 5;
    }
    else
        s++;
}
strTemp[i] = 0;
```

Future modifications:

- Create a utility function to store this function.
- Pass the search string as a parameter.
- Determine the search string's length, so the hardcoded 5's can be removed.
- Dynamically allocate the strTemp variable.
- Error checking for empty strings and chars not found.

**EDIT:**

I created a blog post to detail the steps and provide a more flexible solution:

http://www.solutionmaniacs.com/blog/2012/11/25/c-removereplace-characters-in-a-string.html

Comment: Is this homework? (It's okay if it is, just tag it as `[homework]` if appropriate.)

Comment: Any `String.Replace` method in a higher-level language is really going to boil down to `strstr()` in a loop at the C level. C isn't about such high-minded ideals like "abstraction" and "ease of use".

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped me with this solution.  I get a bit spoiled in C# and forget how to do some relatively simple string manipulation in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *s = (char*)strBuffer;
char sClean[strlen(strBuffer) + 1]; /* +1 for null-byte */
/* if above does not work in your compiler, use:
    char *sClean = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strBuffer) + 1);
*/
int i=0;
while (*s)
{
    sClean[i++]= *s;
    if ((*s == '&') && (!strncmp(s, "&amp;", 5)) s += 5;
    else s++;
}
sClean[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays (like `char sClean[strlen(strBuffer)];` above) are C99 only, and aren't fully supported by a large number of compilers.

Comment: Noted. If Q's compiler can;t do it, Q can use malloc.

Comment: Also note that your code doesn't check for `"&amp;"` - it will overwrite any five characters following the `'&'` character.

Comment: Another problem is the size of sClean is strlen(strBuffer). If there is nothing to replace, the code above has memory violation.

Answer (score 6):

C isn't noted for it's ease of use, especially when it comes to strings, but it has some rather nice standard library functions that will get the job done. If you need to work extensively on strings you'll probably need to know about pointers and pointer arithmetic, but otherwise here are some library functions that will undoubtedly help you:

- [`strchr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) to find a character (say, `'&'`) in a string.
- [`strcmp()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) and [`strncmp()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html) to compare two strings.
- [`strstr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) to find a substring in a string (probably easier and faster than using the `strchr()`/`strcmp()` combination).
- [`malloc()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) to allocate a new string.

Comment: Thanks ... there are a whole lot of standard C functions that can be quite handy!

Comment: Don't forget to use the mem* functions!

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to:

- use the [`strstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) function to find the "&amp;"s
- copy characters to the resulting buffer up to the position found
- skip 4 characters
- repeat until NUL

Comment: You might use `strstr()` but you can also use `strchr()` to find the '&'s and then see if the next few characters are "&amp;": `char *amp = strchr(string, '&'); if(amp && !strncmp(amp, "&amp;") { /* we found it! */ }` Though this is probably just a less optimized version of `strstr()` (which I'm miffed I forgot about).

Comment: Using strstr() is more generic and convenient. It may also be faster, depending on how strstr() is implemented. I recommend his approach. If speed is really a concern, more sophisticated algorithm like KMP is preferred; but I guess Edward Leno just needs something convenient.

Comment: @Chris In this case you're essentially just manually doing the strstr() work inside of your conditional block.  I'd think it would be wiser to use the standard function to mitigate potential errors.

Comment: Actually I prefer "if(amp && !strncmp(amp+1, "amp;") { /* we found it! */ }" and memcpy could be better to use for the actual compacting rather than an indexed iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate another buffer, either on the stack or the heap, and then copy the string into the new buffer 1 character at a time.   Make special handling when you encounter the `&` character.

Comment: That's an array literal, and it can be changed because it's stored in an array. A `char *c = "string";` can't be. But yes, you shouldn't change it to safeguard against making this kind of mistake in the future.

Comment: Actually, in the example posted (unless it's been edited after your answer) strBuffer is a buffer that is writable and is initialized by copying the literal string into the buffer.

Comment: sorry you're right it is an array literal: sizeof(strBuffer) == 249

Comment: I would say definitely allocate the new buffer on the heap. This kind of functionality is definitely something that should be abstracted away into a separate function, so you'd need to use the heap to pass things around (or require the caller pass in his/her own buffer).

Comment: I prefer the passing in your own buffer to a helper function way.