# How to remove a carriage return from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, carriage-return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove characters from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499939/remove-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Do you have an example of C code to remove carriage returns in a string?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Is this homework? And when you say "carriage returns", do you mean 0xD only, or linefeeds (0xA) as well?

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced the supposed dupe _is_ a dupe. It was specifically asking how to replace `&amp` with `&` (despite the erroneous title). Granted there are crossovers in the answers but that doesn't necessarily make the _question_ a dupe.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution is to probably just process the string character by character, with pointers for source and destination:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
    char str[] = "This is a two-line\r\nstring with DOS line endings.\r\n";
    printf("%d [%s]\n",strlen(str), str);

    // ========================
    // Relevant code in this section.
    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != '\r') dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    // ========================

    printf("%d [%s]\n",strlen(str), str);
}
```

This sets up two pointers initially the same. It then copies a character and always advances the source pointer. However, it only advances the destination pointer if the character wasn't a carriage return. That way, all carriage returns are overwritten by either the next character or the null terminator. The output is:

```
51 [This is a two-line
string with DOS line endings.
]
49 [This is a two-line
string with DOS line endings.
]
```

This would be adequate for most strings. If your strings are truly *massive* in size (or this is something you need to do *many* times each second), you could look at a `strchr`-based solution since the library function will most likely be optimised.

Comment: This gives me the result "Ti satolnsrn ihDSln nig."

Comment: @Fred, I accidentally had two `src++` statements, fixed now.

Comment: That works better, if the idea is to remove carriage returns and leave newline characters.  I'm not sure what the OP's intent is.

Comment: `strlen` returns a `size_t`, so you should use the '%zu' format in `printf`.

Comment: schot, you're no doubt correct but it's irrelevant to the question. The `printf` was simply infrastructure so that you could test the relevant bit. You could equally complain that I didn't provide enough test cases.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I know and your answer is OK (+1). But with every code snippet you post you set an example. I would equally complain about `void main()` :)

Answer (score 4):

A carriage return or any other char is easy to replace in a string and even easier to replace. Your question does not really shows what you're looking for so I've included sample code for both removing and replacing a char in a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_char_from_string(char c, char *str)
{
    int i=0;
    int len = strlen(str)+1;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == c)
        {
            // Move all the char following the char "c" by one to the left.
            strncpy(&str[i],&str[i+1],len-i);
        }
    }
}

void replace_char_from_string(char from, char to, char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = strlen(str)+1;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == from)
        {
            str[i] = to;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *original = "a\nmultiline\nstring";
    int original_len = strlen(original)+1;

    char *string = (char *)malloc(original_len);
    memset(string,0,original_len);
    strncpy(string,original,original_len);

    replace_char_from_string('\n',' ',string);
    printf("String: %s\n",string); // print: String: a multiline string

    remove_char_from_string(' ',string);
    printf("String: %s\n",string); // print: String: amultilinestring

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your replace character section was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: in  remove_char_from_string has to be i-- in condition when char is found. Otherwise multiple occurrence char consecutively in string return wrong result