# why comparing 2 equal strings(printing on screen) with strcmp function give wrong answer?

Tags: c, sockets

I tried to compare 2 IP Addresses stored in 2 character arrays. I get the first IP Add char array from socket and the second IP Add char array from text file. When I use strcmp function, I got a non-zero value(which means 2 strings are not equal) although when I tried to printf on the screen , they are equal.
Any idea about my prob?

Comment: Perhaps one has a non-visible character such as space, tab or return

Comment: Maybe you can `strncmp` to the length of the shorter one: `strncmp(s1, s2, min(strlen(s1), strlen(s2)))`. Mind that that makes `"1.2.3.4"` compare equal to `"1.2.3.42"`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem is a special character like '\n', '\r', ... in your char array (from text file). Try to delete them ;-)

[How to remove a carriage return from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796479/how-to-remove-a-carriage-return-from-a-string-in-c/3796582#3796582)

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you pls advise me (with any code or whatever ) on how can i get rid of them