# Remove characters from a string in C

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove characters from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499939/remove-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

I'm creating a small todo application in C and I'd like to remove `*` then a `space` from a string I'm looping over each line then checking if the `lineNumber` is the one passed in to the function then I'd wondering how to remove the characters from that line, Heres the code where I loop over the lines

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, oldTodoFile)) {
        len = strlen(line);
        if (len && (line[len - 1] != '\n')) {} else {
            lineNumber++;
            if (lineNumber == todoNumber) {
              // remove *[space]
            } else {
                fprintf(todoFile);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why C for a text processing app?

Comment: Where exactly is the question in your phrase?

Comment: I've updated the question to make a clear (I think) and I'm using C because I'm trying to learn C

Comment: Please use the search before asking new questions. (Ironically, the existing question has *the exact same title*)

Comment: You could read the file in character by character discarding the unwanted characters. That is probably the easiest way to do it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking how to remove a leading `'* '` from the *beginning* of a string. You have two options:

- You can either just move each character two spaces back, something like:

  ```
  if(startsWithStarSpace) {
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < len; ++i)
      str[i-2] = str[i];
    str[i] = '\0';
  }
  ```
- Or if your string is dynamically allocated, you can just move the pointer forward by two characters (making sure to save your old pointer to `free()` later).

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do this (note i know this is not the best way, i'm sure there is lots of standard functions for this) would be:

```
if(lineNumber == todoNumber) {
 char buff[len];
 char* bptr = buff;
 char* lptr = line;
 for(;lptr!=NULL;) {
  if(*lptr!='*')
   *bptr++ = *lptr++
  else{
   lptr++;lptr++; /*skip over * and space */
  }
 }
 strcpy(line,buff); /* replace line with updated version */
}
```

Like I said, not the best solution but its one way to do it.