# How to remove dash from a string, using C?

Tags: c

C is a new language for me. So some things I learned in other languages don't work here. I created a program that reads a string from the user, and what happens is when there is a dash (-) in the string, I want to remove it, just remove it, I tried to do that by the conventional method `var x = ""`, but it didn't work. Sure, that's just an example, I know it doesn't work in C, but you got the idea.

**Source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    char input[50];
    int i;

    scanf("%s", input);
    
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '-')
        {
            input[i] = "" // Does not remove the dash
        }
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", input);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried: `input[i] = '\0'` and it does not work as well. How can I fix it?

Example of how I want it to be:

Input: 333-55792
Output: 33355792

Comment: oh, boy, this must be a duplicate.  You've got to move all the characters following the space.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499939/remove-characters-from-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a very simple answer in the duplicate. Removing single characters is much easier than removing strings of characters, since we can easily find them.

I will point out that you should not call `strlen` a lot in C. `strlen` counts all the characters, so it is O(n), making your loop O(n^2).  C uses null terminated strings, so inserting a `'\0'` ends the string. You can also use this fact to terminate your loop.

There are easier ways to do this using pointers, but for a beginner, I'll give an array like solution

```
int dashes = 0;
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '-')
    {
        dashes++;
    }
    else if (dashes > 0)
    {
        input[i-dashes] = input[i];
    }
}
// now, null terminate, could do this changing our loop test, but
// this is easier to understand. 
input[i-dashes] = '\0';
```

Comment: That's it! Simple as should be. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

C is not a high level language. You need to do the manual work of shifting the characters to left skipping dashes:

```
int from = 0;
int to = 0;

while (str[from] != '\0')
{
    if (str[from] == '-')
    {
         ++from;
         continue;
    }
    str[to] = str[from];
    ++to;
    ++from;
}

str[to] = '\0';
```